# How can i get arrays intersection include duplicate values using Javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need something like lodash.intersectionWith but I also need duplicated values in result array.

Example:

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
_.intersectionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);
```

Expected Result:

```
[{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 },{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not exactly clear why you expect there to be 2 copies of that object and not 3.

Comment: Because array #1 has 2 values matching array #2 I'd guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the intersection by filtering out items from the first array that don't match items in the second. Any duplicates in the first array will be kept.

```js
var intersectwith = function(f,xs,ys){
    return xs.filter(function(x){
        return ys.some(function(y){
            return f(x,y);
        });
    });
};

var equals = function(x,y){
    return x === y;
};
console.log(intersectwith(equals, [1,2,3], [1,1,2,2,4]));
console.log(intersectwith(equals, [1,1,2,2,4], [1,2,3]));
```

Or, more readably, using ES6:

```js
const intersectwith = (f,xs,ys) => xs.filter(x => ys.some(y => f(x,y)));
const equals = (x,y) => x === y;

console.log(intersectwith(equals, [1,2,3], [1,1,2,2,4]));
console.log(intersectwith(equals, [1,1,2,2,4], [1,2,3]));
```

Substitute `_.isEqual` for `equals` for comparing objects: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78sr0L04/).

Useful documentation:
[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: You can use a different comparison function, e.g. `_.isEqual`. I wanted to show it working in the code snippet.

Comment: Edited to add jsfiddle showing it in action with objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [differenceWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith) to get the difference between the source `object` and the symmetric difference of the source `object` and the `others` object using [xorWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#xorWith).

```
var result = _.differenceWith(
  objects, 
  _.xorWith(objects, others, _.isEqual), 
  _.isEqual
);
```

```js
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];


var intersection = _.intersectionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);

var result = _.differenceWith(
  objects, 
  _.xorWith(objects, others, _.isEqual), 
  _.isEqual
);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like this approach, but here is one problem, my actual arrays have different object types 'objects are Jquery' and 'others are javascript object'. The problem is that [xorWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#xorWith)'s comparator function at some point switches arguments (have no idea why).

Comment: @Mikhail please check my update, I changed [difference()](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) to [differenceWith()](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith).

Comment: intersectionWith() works fine. I made a [test](http://codepen.io/mikhail_vasilchenko/pen/JKPKJE?editors=1112) you can check it out.

Comment: I can see that in your [test](http://codepen.io/mikhail_vasilchenko/pen/JKPKJE?editors=1112), the source `object` does only contain the `x` and `y` property. You should have added such statement. And your test definitely failed. If you log the intersection `result` it would return an empty array.

Comment: I update [demo](http://codepen.io/mikhail_vasilchenko/pen/JKPKJE?editors=1112). But any way it is just to see the difference between Xor and Intersection comparator functions.

Comment: moreover lodash pullAllWith removes all duplicated values and can be used like workaround if you don't care about 'objects' array. Here [demo](http://codepen.io/mikhail_vasilchenko/pen/vKByEE?editors=0012)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` to validate each `object` in the first `array`, then check if that `object` exists in the second `array`. If it exists, `reduce` will `push` that `object` into its `array`.

The `reduce` function will return that new `array` automagically.

```js
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

var res = objects.reduce(
  function(arr, obj){
    if(containsObject(obj, others))
      arr.push(obj);
    return arr;
  }, 
  []
);


function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var x;
    var ret = false;
  
    list.forEach(function(s){
      ret = JSON.stringify(s) == JSON.stringify(obj);
    });

    return ret;
}

console.log(res);
```